# Vue js don't get the route params when you click on button. Update user from firestore

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I want to update the username with firestore but I don't get the url of the document.
What only works is that I can only update the data of the user that is now logged in. But I want to access all of the user and update them.

**Here is the (router-link) button**

```
<tbody>
    <tr v-for="Profiles in Profile" :key="Profiles.id">
      <td>{{Profiles.username}}</td>
      <td>{{Profiles.email}}</td>
      <td>{{Profiles.userId}}</td>
      <td>{{Profiles.role}}</td>
      <td>{{Profiles.haveAccess}}</td>
      <td>{{Profiles.createdAt}}</td>
      <router-link :to="{ name: 'Update', params: {id: Profiles.id} }" class="btn btn-warning removeUnderline">
        <v-btn color="warning" small class="mt-2">Update</v-btn>
      </router-link>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

**This is my router file**

```
 {
    name: 'Update',
    path: '/Update/:id',
    component: Update,
    props: route => ({
      profile: route.params.id // maps route param "id" to prop "profileId"
    })
  },
```

**And my Update.vue file**

```
    <div>
        <h1>update</h1>
        <v-form v-on:submit.prevent="update">
            <v-container>
                <v-text-field
                    type="text"
                    v-model="username"
                    :counter="10"
                    required
                ></v-text-field>
                <input type="submit" @click="update" class="btn primary mt-3" value="Save"/>
            </v-container>
        </v-form>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
/*eslint-disable-line*/import { db } from '../../Database';
import firebase from 'firebase';
export default {
    props: { profileId: String },
    data() {
        return {
            Profile: [],
            username: ''
        }
    },
    methods: {
        async update() {
            // const data = {
            //     username: this.username,
            // };
            // const res = await db.collection('Profile').doc(/*this.profileId*/this.currentUser.toString()).update({
            //     username: this.username
            // });
            await db.collection('Profile').doc(String(this.profileId)).update({
                username: this.username
            });
            console.log('updated' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
            // console.log(res + data)
        }
    },
    firestore: {
        Profile: db.collection('Profile')
    }
}
</script>
```

**My firestore database**
[image]

**The error what I get after with the new code**

[image]

**I got now the document of the Firestore**

`http://localhost:8080/Update/bRiKnCX6LVQoxotLywp9zO9UctF3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I think the property you want to use is `id`, **not** `.key` (see the examples at https://vuefire.vuejs.org/vuefire/binding-subscriptions.html#using-the-data-bound-by-vuefire)

```html
<tr v-for="userProfile in Profile" :key="userProfile.id">
  <td>{{userProfile.username}}</td>
  <td>{{userProfile.email}}</td>
  <td>{{userProfile.userId}}</td>
  <td>{{userProfile.role}}</td>
  <td>{{userProfile.haveAccess}}</td>
  <td>{{userProfile.createdAt}}</td>
  <td> <!--  you were missing a TD here -->
    <router-link
      :to="{ name: 'Update', params: { id: userProfile.id } }"
      class="btn btn-warning removeUnderline"
    >
      <v-btn color="warning" small class="mt-2">Update</v-btn>
    </router-link>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Now, get Vue Router to pass the `id` route param to your component as a prop

```js
// route file
{
    name: 'Update',
    path: '/Update/:id',
    component: Update,
    props: route => ({
      profileId: route.params.id // maps route param "id" to prop "profileId"
    })
},
```

```js
// Update.vue
export default {
  props: { profileId: String },
  // etc
}
```

Now instead of using `this.currentUser`, use `this.profileId` to use the ID passed in via the URL.

```js
await db.collection('Profile').doc(this.profileId).update({
  username: this.username
});
```

See [Passing Props to Route Components](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html).

Comment: I tried to use your code but I think that it can't get the document of the Firestore. It says only undefined. The userId of firebase (auth) is the same as the document of Firestore. Check the screenshots above.

Comment: Sounds like the `.key` property doesn't actually exist on your `Profiles` object. Have you checked that it is the correct property to use?

Comment: I got now the id of the document in the url I changed the `.key` to `:key="userProfile.id"`. But I can't update because it says `No document to update`. I updated the code above there you can see the screenshot of the error.

Comment: Ah sorry, my mistake. It's just a typo in the router file. Will fix it now

Comment: I change now the router file to this: I replace this code `profile: route.params.id` to ` profileId: route.params.id` I forgot to do that. Now thanks to you I can update my users Profiles. But I have one little error in my router url. When I go to the Update file and I click on the link in the sidebar then the url becomes this: `http://localhost:8080/Update/Home`. Do you know why?

Comment: Without seeing the code for that, sorry no. If I had to guess, you've got `to="Home"` but you should use `to="/Home"` or even better, use named routes `:to="{ name: 'Home' }"`